# How does parent tag Attributes in the "apply templete" when it is in "group by"

Tags: xslt

Here is the Sample XML which I am using

**XML.xml**

```
<root>
    <main>
        <docum year="2022" month="2022.01">1</docum>
        <docum year="2021" month="2021.12">2</docum>
        <docum year="2020" month="2020.11">3</docum>
        <docum year="2020" month="2020.12">4</docum>
        <docum year="2022" month="2022.12">5</docum>
    </main>
</root>
```

Need a navigator HTML which is `toc.htm` and `1.htm`, `2.htm`, `3.htm`

**toc.htm**

```
<div>
    <div><a href="1.htm">2022_2022.01</a></div>
    <div><a href="2.htm">2022_2022.12</a></div>
    <div><a href="3.htm">2022_2020.11</a></div>
</div>
```

**1.htm**

```
<div>
    <h1>2022</h1>
    <h2>2022.01</h2>
    1
</div>
<div>
    <h1>2022</h1>
    <h2>2022.12</h2>
    5
</div>
```

**2.htm**

```
<div>
    <h1>2021</h1>
    <h2>2021.12</h2>
    2
</div>
```

**3.htm**

```
<div>
    <h1>2020</h1>
    <h2>2020.11</h2>
    3
</div>
<div>
    <h1>2020</h1>
    <h2>2020.11</h2>
    4
</div>
```

this is my XSL which I am trying but not sure about how we get parent div attributes value in the apply template in the current group().

**XSL.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="main" mode="toc" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="main" mode="chapter" />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="root/main" mode="toc">
    <xsl:result-document href="toc.htm" method="html">
        <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:for-each select="docum">
                <xsl:element name="div">
                    <xsl:attribute name="class"></xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="id">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@year" />
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:element name="a">
                        <xsl:attribute name="href">
                            <xsl:value-of select="lower-case(concat('id_', generate-id(), '.htm'))" />
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@year" /> _<xsl:value-of select="@month" />
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="root/main" mode="chapter">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="docum" group-by="@month">
        <xsl:result-document href="{lower-case(concat('id_', generate-id()))}.htm" method="HTML">
            <html>
            <body>
                <h1><xsl:value-of select="@year" /></h1>
                <h2><xsl:value-of select="@month" /></h2>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
            </body>
            </html>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You have `xsl:template match="root"` but I don't see any `root` element at all in your XML sample. Furthermore you use `<xsl:for-each-group select="main" group-by="@month">` but the `main` element doesn't have any `@month` attribute. Consider to explain in your text which result, based on which criteria, you want to produce, the output samples together with that code don't make it clear.

Comment: Hello I have corrected the Sample XML & XSL, Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve, your sample seems to have five different `month` attribute values so your grouping code would create five groups.

Comment: I want to group by year and show the year  & month value from the parent tag to show inside the current-group(), you can see in the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something along the following lines:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

<xsl:template match="root/main">
  <xsl:result-document href="toc.html">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>TOC</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="docum" group-by="@year">
          <div id="g-{current-grouping-key()}">
            <a href="year-{current-grouping-key()}.html">{let $sorted-months := sort(current-group()/@month, (), function($m) { $m }) return $sorted-months[1] || ('-' || $sorted-months[last()])[$sorted-months[2]]}</a>
          </div>
          <xsl:result-document href="year-{current-grouping-key()}.html">
            <html>
              <head>
                <title>{current-grouping-key()}</title>
              </head>
              <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
              </body>
            </html>
          </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each-group>        
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="docum">
  <div>
    <h1>{@year}</h1>
    <h2>{@month}</h2>
    {.}
  </div>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This creates toc.html and for each year a `year-yyyy.html` which I think then has the contents you want, i.e. each month belonging to that year.

Comment: Hello @Martin Honnen sir, How do I get all the template styling inside `{.}`, in this case, I am getting all text wrapped in a `div` in the simple text, but what if there are some tags. How do I get the Styling? if you suggest it would be tremendously helpful.

Comment: `{.}` is the use of a text value template, it creates a (plain) text node, you can only style element nodes. Perhaps `<xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>` instead of `{.}` helps, but I can't say without seeing the input and the wanted output, therefore raise a new question if you can't figure it out based on this comment.